# Whats going to happen to former files when installing Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: files, backup

I'm about to test out and probably upgrade my Windows Vista to the latest Ubuntu, and I was wondering what do I need to do in order to keep all my files so they are ready for Ubuntu.

I'm obviously going to back up everything just in case, but outside of whats on my computer's native HDD, do I need to back up what is already on an external HDD?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats going to happen to former files when installing Ubuntu Desktop?

That depends on what you do during install. If you format a partition the files are gone. On the other hand it is totally possible to format C: and not format D: where D: ends up as "/dev/sda2" partition you can mount.

> do I need to back up what is already on an external HDD?

No. For extra safety I would advice to unplug external media.  When you plug in external hdd's Ubuntu will recognize them and mount them accordingly. Even NTFS. In the rare occasion it does not you can still mount it manually.

A backup of personal files will be sufficient. I would advice to check upfront if you can restore the files.

If you jump into Ubuntu by removing Windows completely feel free but if you set up a dual boot you must *shutdown* your machine. Do not restart from hibernation or suspend since that will leave Windows in an unclean state (and Ubuntu will inform you about that but will refuse to mount is).